# Redirecting macro definition in Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, logging, crashlytics

I am currently using the "Flexible Logging" as shown [here](http://brenwill.com/2010/flexible-ios-logging/), for example:

```
LogInfo(@"Do you object to this %@ date object?", [NSDate new]);
LogDebug(@"I'll take this out if ever I solve this bug");
LogError(@"Don't do that: %@", [NSException exceptionWithName: @"CRYING" reason: @"Spilled milk" userInfo:nil]);
```

I have now added the Crashlytics library to my project and this to the Prefix.pch:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define CLS_LOG(__FORMAT__, ...) CLSNSLog((@"%s line %d $ " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define CLS_LOG(__FORMAT__, ...) CLSLog((@"%s line %d $ " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Is there a way to redirect all log messages from LogInfo, LogDebug, LogError, etc. to CLS_LOG?

I did this for TestFlight:

```
#define NSLog TFLog
```

But doing the same for Crashlytics does not work, and gives warnings about redefining macros:

```
 #define LogDebug CLS_LOG
```

Comment: Using #undef might help you.

Comment: Won't the format of the custom loggers be lost by using #undef?

Comment: Not if you make your macro call through to them.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I don't think you're showing us all the relevant parts of the file this is defined in.  CLANG should show you where both definitions reside, and that should help you determine if you need to either remove or `#undef` one or the other.

Comment: See the first link for the full custom logger definition.

Comment: But that's not *your* code.  I want to see your code, not some blog post.

Comment: I have not changed the code, it is as is from the blog post. That's why I provided the link. Here's a pastebin for the lazy - http://pastebin.com/PaX0h5VX

Comment: Yeah, I can't reproduce this with the code you've provided.  The only thing I can recommend is actually reading the warning (again, CLANG will literally point to both definitions if what you say is correct) and fixing what you can by either `#undef`ing or removing one or the other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47280/discussion-between-ebi-and-codafi)